# React - Refactoring hook with partial applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have the following hook:

```js
function sendMessage(toId, text) { ... }

const useSendMessage = ({ onSuccess, onError } = {}) => {
  const { showRewardedAd } = useAdMob();
 
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleOnEarnMessagesReward = () => {
    // increase total available messages...
  };

  const handleOnRewardedAdError = (error) => {
     toast.warning(error); // display the error using a toast...

     //
     // QUESTION: HOW TO PASS toId and text args?
     //

     // do not block the app due to the AdMob service...
     handleOnEarnMessagesReward(); // fake reward
     sendMessage();
  };
 
  const sendMessageOrDisplayAd = (toId, text) => { 
    if (!user.totalAvailableMessages) {
      return showRewardedAd({
        onEarnReward: handleOnEarnMessagesReward,
        onError: handleOnRewardedAdError,
      });
    }

    // No need to open a rewarded ad
    sendMessage(toId, text);
    user.totalAvailableMessages -= 1; 
  }

  return {
    isLoading,
    error,
    sendMessageOrDisplayAd
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am not receiving the `toId` and `text` params as arguments in `useSendMessage`...

In order to execute the `handleOnRewardedAdError` method correctly, should I use a partial application like:

```js
  const handleOnRewardedAdError = (toId, text) => (error) => {
     toast.warning(error); // display the error using a toast...

     // do not block the app due to the AdMob service...
     handleOnEarnMessagesReward(); // fake reward
     sendMessage(toId, text); <--------------------
  };

  const sendMessageOrDisplayAd = (toId, text) => { 
    if (!user.totalAvailableMessages) {
      return showRewardedAd({
        onEarnReward: handleOnEarnMessagesReward,
        onError: handleOnRewardedAdError(toId, text), <------------------
      });
    }

    // No need to open a rewarded ad
    sendMessage(toId, text);
    user.totalAvailableMessages -= 1; 
  }
```

This seems logical to me, but is this an anti-pattern or bad practice? Any other strategy to solve this problem?

Comment: You could consider the API from the perspective of testing as that can lead to a nice design and composition. I use partial application every once in a while but in this case I would write the whole function inline and avoid indirection as potential for reuse seems low (I may be wrong here as I don't see all of the code).

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen Yes, the potential for reuse is low. When you say 'inline', you mean an es6+ anonymous arrow function inside the body of `sendMessageOrDisplayAd`, right?

Comment: Exactly, I would write an anonymous function like that and have the logic there until there's a good reason to change it.